# Why was the "Green" removed from "Green Arrow"?

Tags: arrowverse, arrow, comic-adaptation

Why was the new TV version of *Green Arrow*, simply called *Arrow*? Have the studios given any reasoning behind that decision?

Comment: Spoiler: In the third season, he renames himself to "Green Arrow" to show that he changed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Writer and co-executive producer [Andrew Kreisberg says](http://tv.yahoo.com/blogs/fall-tv/shows-arrow-revolution-hit-bulls-eye-archery-craze-005549551.html):

> ***[dropped] the "Green" from the title because "Arrow" felt "sexier, a little more dangerous.***

But I think the name change also reflects that this version is noticably different from the *Smallville* incarnation, but also from the *Comics*.

Lead actor [Stephen Amell says](http://blog.zap2it.com/frominsidethebox/2012/05/10-spoilers-arrow-stands-apart-from-smallville-plus-teen-wolf-season-2-scoop-and-a-new-face-on-homel.html):

> ***Nobody in our universe has super powers**, so that's a big jumping off point...*
>
> *Other than in name, there are virtually no similarities between [the 'Smallville' version and the new version].*

A world without superpowered characters would definately be a very big difference.

Pilot director/executive producer [David Nutter says](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2012/03/19/first-look-at-arrow):

> *When I directed the pilot for 'Smallville', I knew that making Clark Kent relatable would be the key to audiences believing in him as a hero. **ARROW is a different show — darker and harder-edged** — but it’s the same core idea. **We’re creating a real, believable world** in which Oliver Queen can do incredible things.*

They have also renamed *Star City* to *Starling City* and changed Oliver Queen's hair color and family constellation.

Comment: I like how the Luthur Mansion in Smallville is actually the Queen Mansion in Arrow haha. +1 for this answer

Comment: __Note:__ Season 2 will [introduce](http://screenrant.com/arrow-show-flash-actor-grant-gustin/) _Flash_, so the _"no super powers"_ part is no longer true.

Comment: @Oliver_C That depends on how "flashy" that *Flash* is going to be, I think.

Comment: Still, one of another biggest notable difference is TV's arrow is not funny at all. comic's arrow is very lightweight guy and had smile on his face. TV's arrow has more similarities to Batman. (having Bat's villians and all)

Answer (score 9):

This [article](http://screenrant.com/cw-arrow-tv-trailer-yman-172887/) from Screenrant suggests that it was done to reach a wider audience. Presumably the name "Arrow" might attract people who could be turned off by the comic-book-sounding name "Green Arrow." Anyway, it seems he is more about the Arrow now than the Green:

[image]
[image]